# Where can I get a dependable data stream of stock prices?

Tags: equities, tick-data, latency, feed

I want a dependable stream of second-by-second stock data. I have looked into [quantgo](http://quantgo.com), [iqFeed](https://www.iqfeed.net) and QuantHouse. Quantgo and iqFeed seem decent. QuantHouse with its ultra low latency speeds seems like overkill for what I am looking for but may be of some use later. I am not looking for the cheapest, but for the most dependable.

Does anyone have either any experience with any of them or know of a company that offers such real time date feeds.

Comment: I have heard of eSignal Signature http://www.esignal.com/products/signature/?tc= but I haven't used it. I have used Bloomberg but it is pricey.

Comment: What about Bloomberg or Reuters?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have strict low latency requirements and don't care if the provider is conflating tick data, then I would recommend using a broker's market data feed. Many electronic brokers offer access to connect to streaming market data alongside their other services. This will be the cheapest option in terms of cost, and will also likely be the easiest to develop on.

If you need an enterprise solution, and can afford to pay several thousand dollars a month, then the likes of Bloomberg, ActiveX, SR Labs, IDC, S&P's Quanthouse, are some of the big providers out there that I am acquainted with.

For high fidelity, ultra low latency requirements, I would recommend either MayStreet's Bellport or SR Labs.

In addition to factors such as latency, data fidelity, and cost, I would also consider the following:

1. How easy is it to develop on their api ? Does their api service model satisfy your application's requirements ?
2. In terms of tick data, do they provide only the inside market ? Level 1 data ? Level 2 data ? What other auxiliary data do they offer ?
3. What options are there to connect into their feeds ? Internet ? Collocate ? Vpn ? Something else ?
4. What is the universe of securities they support ?
5. In addition to raw tick data, what sorts of aggregate and summary data do they offer ?
6. How capable is their IT ? Do they respond quickly and with useful answers or no ?
7. Does their api have methods to recover from connection drops, session corrupted, server failover, etc ? How robust are these procedures ?
8. What symbology schema do they use to lookup and request data ? Is it consistent with your system's symbology ?
9. What sort of data limits do they impose ? Do they offer a test server to develop on ?

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Cheap, accurate, fast: choose two.

IQFeed is the cheapest broker-neutral feed that I know of for this and they have reasonable accuracy.

Otherwise, brokers often package in a data feed for free.

QuantHouse's feed etc. are about 2 orders of magnitude more expensive.